# Bypassing async while getting image size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am get the image size (width x height). The image is location is URL. I tried something like below code block

```
var constants: {
       standImgDim: {
           small: '200x200',
           mid: '400x400'
       }
    };
```

---

```
this.getImgDim = function(targetImg) {
        var width=0, height=0, setStyleWidth = 0;
        $("<img/>")
            .attr("src", targetImg)
            .load(function() {
                width = this.width;
                height = this.height;
                var gotDim = width+'x'+height;

                    console.log(gotDim);
            });
   console.log('data');

    };
```

Current output:

```
data
200x200
```

Expected output:

```
200x200
data
```

I know the result is coming due to async behavior...

I also tried with $.Deferred.. but it won't work. As i am not using ajax (as below )

var deferred = new $.Deferred();

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: targetImg,
                    dataType: "image/jpeg"
                }).done(function(data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).fail(function(error) {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });

                return deferred.promise();
```

Is there any way to do it in sync way/other ?

Comment: no, you cannot bypass async. Show us how you've tried to use deferreds.

Comment: `$.Deferred` doesn't have anything to do with Ajax. If it doesn't work for you, you haven't used it correctly.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle for us so we can help you further

Answer (score 0):

Add a callback in the load function:

```
this.getImgDim = function(targetImg, callback) {
        var width=0, height=0, setStyleWidth = 0;
        $("<img/>")
            .attr("src", targetImg)
            .load(function() {
                width = this.width;
                height = this.height;
                var gotDim = width+'x'+height;

                    console.log(gotDim);

                callback();
            });


    };

this.getImgDim('targetImage', function () {
       console.log('data');
});
```

The only function that async is `.load` so what the callback allows, is the code to come back to the synchronous context somewhat, if you need to access some variables or some output data of the load function, you can pass that through the callback.

I think you can even pass the context through as well by doing:

```
callback.bind(this);
```